# Is it possible to keep the Windows' compositor working normally when using a fullscreen OpenGL application?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, dwm

Under Windows, when the DWM composition is active, there's a somehow "special path" for fullscreened OpenGL applications ***that prevents all other subwindows (popups, menus, tooltips) to be correctly layered on top of the fullscreened OpenGL window***.

While this is useful for games and such, it's totally a pain for other fullscreen OpenGL applications (CAD, 3d editors, etc.). This problem is causing endless troubles for Qt users, see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-7556), [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42410), or [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44247).

**Is there a way to tell Windows not to enable the special path for a given application / fullscreen window?** Either in the manifest, or via DWM APIs, I don't care.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done by tricking Windows into thinking that the Window should be composited with transparency. For this you call `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` on the window. In case of a fullscreen WS_POPUP window this makes the window fully transparent (instead of the glass effect) and you can use the window's alpha channel to control the opacity; for a regular window with a title area and border you get the glassy effect then.

Now if you configure the pixelformat without an alpha channel or set the alpha channel to all 1 (full opacity) the compositor still has to assume some transparency may be present and goes through full composition.

#### Small update

Although WinXP and Win2k are beyond their EOL, it may be undesireable to hardlink the `dwmapi.dll` to the executable, e.g. if you have to support legacy systems with your software for some reason. For that I wrote a small wrapper library [`dwm_load`](https://github.com/datenwolf/dwm_load) that dynamically loads the dwmapi.dll if available or falls back to failsafe implementation of the DWM functions.

Comment: That's a very nice idea! Let me try it out. I've already added `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` calls into Qt [a long time ago](https://codereview.qt-project.org/63716)...

Comment: Sigh, apparently the trick doesn't quite work. The very same window, which in non-fullscreen is correctly shown with transparency, and has working menus/popups/etc., ceases to have transparency (black background, no menus/etc.) as soon as I make it fullscreen.

Comment: @peppe: How are you making your Window fullscreen? I'd like to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The overall code in Qt is a bit convoluted, but the relevant code path is [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp.html#1663). It's basically a call to `SetWindowLongPtr` (see setStyle) plus `SetWindowPos`. (Needless to say, everything works fine for non GL top levels).

Comment: Just an update: the current proposed workarounds are 1) make the window 1pixel bigger/smaller than real fullscreen; or 2) add a 1px border via `WS_BORDER` (see [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/114250/)). Of course none of those are really optimal :(

Comment: @peppe: I've been working on some workarounds (none successful so far)  as well. Interesting problem.